# Java Build Enviroment configuration in Classes or TextFiles?

Tags: java, properties, build, maven-assembly-plugin

I use the maven assembly plugin to build difrent jars (test-properties.jar and prod-properties.jar) with the properties (test1.properties and test2.properties) inside for the enviroment Test and Production. Now i changend the propertie files (test1.properties and test2.properties) into Java Files (Test1.java and Test2.java)... compile them and run the assembly plugin again.
So i have the two jar Files with the classes inside and it works on the difrent enviroments.

-> test-properties.jar (Test1.class, Test2.class)

-> prod-properties.jar (Test1.class, Test2.class)

If i deploy the Webapp on Produktion, then i use the prod-properties.jar for the Deployment. For the Local Workspace i use the test-properties.jar

My Question: Is it better to use Enviroment Properties with properties Files or Java Classes inside? (Performance? Dont need the FileInputStream... Bad Code Style?)

Thank you for the Answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using properties files, Java classes should remain constant between environments and maven has built in resource filtering.

In the multi-module project I am working on at the moment I have a properties file which is dynamically set, depending on the profile/environment I use:

The dynamic property points to a registration URL for my project, and is environment specific. It is defined in the properties file as the following:

```
REGISTRATION_URL=${REGISTRATION_URL}
```

I can then specify the registration URL in a maven profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>test-environment</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>environment</name>
            <value>test</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <REGISTRATION_URL>http://test-env/register</REGISTRATION_URL>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

From here, there are two ways to apply this profile specific property:

1. apply resource filtering in the build section of the module's POM which contains the properties file:

   ```
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Specify resource filtering within a moduleSet or fileSet within your assembly. In my case I use moduleSet:

   ```
   <moduleSet>
       <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
       <includes>
           <include>${project.groupId}:core-module</include>
       </includes>
       <sources>
           <fileSets>
               <fileSet>
                   <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                   <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
                   <includes>
                       <include>environment.properties</include>
                   </includes>
                   <filtered>true</filtered>
                </fileSet>
           </fileSets>
           <includeModuleDirectory>false</includeModuleDirectory>
       </sources>
   </moduleSet>
   ```

When the project is built using this profile (-P test-environment) the above property in  environment.properties will be set as the following:

```
REGISTRATION_URL=http://test-env/register
```